# Salvaging another user's question

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

I'd like to try to salvage [another user's question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/what-is-the-oldest-documented-sport), by addressing more precisely the topic, since the original one apparently is too vague to be answered.

Am I supposed to edit his question, or to write a new one?

Comment: Edit. Edit. Edit.

Comment: @edmastermind29 edited, thanks

Comment: @edmastermind29 mmh, edited, but as long as the question is still closed, it doesn't help…

Comment: That's when reopen votes are used.

Comment: @edmastermind29 you, as a mod, can re-open it, and let the community decide if to close it again or not.

Comment: So, because you say I can reopen it, I should reopen it? If it gets another vote or two, I'll reopen it. I would like to see the community agree with this move as well.

Comment: @edmastermind29 I was just suggesting, since you suggested me to edit it. No big deal

Comment: Right. Nothing wrong with editing, because your edit improves the question.

Comment: The question has been reopened!

Answer (score 1):

[Searching](http://bit.ly/18LoIbc)<sup>(1)</sup> the internet, using this query: *oldest sport in the world* will yield:

[image]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_sport

This question could've easily been closed as NARQ.

(1): Google

Comment: I thought this made sense, but I thought a bit more about it and now I don't agree any more. While the original question was bad for this very reason, my subsequent edit has a very precise definition, and the answer to that isn't obvious (nor answered by that link).